# Symfony entityManager findBy() Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to display only active adverts in my view, but I get an error:

> Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "advert".

When I am displaying all adverts, there is no problem:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="advert_index")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $adverts = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render("Advert/index.html.twig", ["adverts" => $adverts]);
}
```

But when I am trying to display only active adverts, I coded:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="advert_index")
 *
 * @param Advert $advert
 * @return Response
 */
public function indexAction(Advert $advert)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $adverts = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findBy(["status" => $advert->getStatus() === Advert::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    $adverts = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findBy([$advert->getStatus() === Advert::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    $adverts = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findBy($advert->getStatus() === Advert::STATUS_ACTIVE);

    return $this->render("Advert/index.html.twig", ["adverts" => $adverts]);
}
```

These are the 3 ways which i tried. But it does not work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: `$adverts = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findBy(["status" => Advert::STATUS_ACTIVE]);` or `$adverts = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findByStatus(Advert::STATUS_ACTIVE);` but you could always declare a custom repository function.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the method signature for your action:

```
public function indexAction(Advert $advert)
```

The Doctrine ParamConverter tries to fetch an advert for you, but since there is no `{id}` in the route itself, the converter is not able to identify which advert to load.

Since you don't want one specific advert removing the parameter should be fine:

```
public function indexAction() 
{
    ...
}
```

Then you can change your findBy-method to just be:

```
findBy(['status' => Advert::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
```

This should give you all active adverts.